# Can I cause auto-correct in Lion to beep and to get a summary of the changes?

Tags: macos, audio

Auto-correct in Lion is great, but I need to know when it has made a substitution so I can check it.

Is there a way to set an audio alert so that OS X makes a sound to alert me everytime it autocorrects?

Is there another way to see a quick summary of the auto-correct changes which have occurred in a document?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a Mac developer I've been working on a solution to this problem, so far I've been able to detect autocorrect in a `NSTextView` within the app itself and play a sound to alert the user.

At the moment I am working on making it able to detect autocorrect in any `NSTextView` in any app but that's a bit harder and may take longer so I thought I would just brief you on what I've done so far.

I'll edit this answer with the final app when it can detect autocorrection in any app.

Here's what I've got done so far: ***[Most up to date download link further down]***

---

I'm currently in the process of testing a version of the app which is generalised and works on every single text view no matter which app is active. It uses a slightly different method to how I did it when it was just a `NSTextView` within the app itself as when you deal with these things with other apps (via the Accesability API) you don't have direct access to the objects themselves.

Anyway enough with the 'jibber-jabber', here are some screen shots of the preferences:

[image]

**General** - At the moment it just lets you choose the sound to play when autocomplete is detected.

[image]

**Blacklist** - Allows you to blacklist certain apps so that autocorrect detection is turned off and no sound is played.

The reason I am testing it is because the method I use is not completely sound, it simply detects any change in text before the cursor. This means it will detect autocomplete but in general will detect any change in text that is NOT directly done by the user (e.g a button which clears all text) other than this it works pretty well.

I'll update this answer with a download link once I've finished testing.

---

[image]

I've finished testing, so… **here's the download link: http://cl.ly/9CIZ**

It runs in the background, so has no dock icon. To access the preferences double click on the app in Finder.

Again, this doesn't work perfectly and has a couple of bugs but it should work 99% of the time!

Comment: Thanks Joshua. This sounds very promising. Your own app certainly works well and reassures that at the very least, app devs will be able to add this. I hope you do find a way to generalise it.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more info about the app.

Comment: Brilliant. Great work!

Comment: Thanks! I've added the download link to the full app now, so you can give it a try!

Comment: Wonderful! Just one minor issue - it seems to disable the blue dotted line which you normally get under auto-corrected words. Also - how do I turn it off?!

Comment: Hmm, that can be right. The app has nothing to do with the blue dotted line as it doesn't have direct access to the text view. And, yes, sorry about that, it isn't very obvious how you turn it off. Just double click on the app icon then hit Command-Q.

Comment: @Joshua, this is great. I just saw this app on [MacStories ](http://www.macstories.net/mac/let-auto-correct-beep-in-lion-with-autocorrectbeeper/) and went to post it here before I realized they were talking about this question and your app. Neato. Ten points!

Comment: Great work, thank you! I also have a suggestion: Perhaps there could also be an option for a visible feedback like a short screen blinking. Sounds disturb others, e.g. while working in library.

Comment: @Arni Here is a version (1.0.2) which has a 'Silent Mode' option which rather than playing a sound makes the text area flash white. http://idzr.org/4d2n

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find any such feature.

Best I can think of is to either write the hack yourself, or to look into a third-party solution.

As for third-party apps, I think [TextExpander](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) allows for audio alerts. I'm sure there are other apps though.

Comment: Typinator also support audio alerts.  http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/