# Is it possible to hack the "Correct spelling automatically" setting in OS X to emit a sound when correcting?

Tags: macos, spellcheck

There are many times when I curse the autocorrection mechanism for changing what I typed, but overall, much of the corrections are welcome so I don't really want to disable it. I do want to have it do it's work but alert me when it makes each change so I don't have to proofread everything or focus with perfect attention to the screen to see the momentary red and/or blue underlining that alerts me to the machine override.

I would love a way to turn on an audible beep (customizable of course) so that I also get a warning each time my typing gets corrected (and only when autocorrection occurs).

Comment: Uh yeah! I'd like to use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=897jlnmTYqE&feature=related) sound.

Comment: I am surprised this is a duplicate...but there you go. Wow. Original has an answer too.

Comment: The other question also looks to see all the changes in a document. I just want the beep :-)

Comment: Answer is the same though.

Comment: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 3):

Not exclusively, but there is a tool that will mark spelling and other changes with a sound.

As described in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20861/14447), it is possible to detect the type of text field change that autocorrect uses programmatically. A sound is issued whenever any of the text changes - but this results in a lot of false positive "sounds" when autocorrect did not happen. A proof of concept app was released August 2011, so I hope it is still fully functioning. Direct download link: http://cl.ly/9CIZ. The app works in the background, and has a few options, such as the sound to be played. The author of the tool states:

> Again, this doesn't work perfectly and has a couple of bugs but it
>   should work 99% of the time!

Comment: Great find. The app seems laggy and not specific to autocorrect. I get beeps several seconds after a substitution and also phantom beeps when no typing is happening... It's a fantastic lead since there is code and something that mostly works!

Comment: In practice this app won't do for me - there are far too many false positive beeps when nothing is happening to work for a signal to check for computer overrides. it is a great hack, though.

Comment: Did you try [version 1.0.2](http://idzr.org/4d2n) ? And [titaniumdecoy](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4076/titaniumdecoy) mentioned [Typinator](http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/) also support audio alerts (system-wide ?): `You can, for example, assign separate feedback sounds for spelling corrections...`

Comment: @iolsmit - I didn't see the newer version and will look into Typinator. I'm not really looking to disable apple's spell check and use another program - but perhaps I don't yet understand typinator's abilities. I appreciate the extra info!