# Sound on Spelling Error

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, spellcheck

I am trying to find a way to get spell checking to play a sound when an error is detected. I don’t mean when an error is “corrected”, but just when one is detected.

A long time ago, you would add a spell checker to your Mac via a third party application. I remember one which made a sound every time it detected an error, which meant that you didn’t have to look at the screen to notice errors.

I don’t think the feature is built into OS X's spelling error correction (why not?). Is there possibly a third part app that will do this simple task?

The following questions hint at the problem:

[Is it possible to hack the "Correct spelling automatically" setting in OS X to emit a sound when correcting?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42549/is-it-possible-to-hack-the-correct-spelling-automatically-setting-in-os-x-to-e?rq=1) & [Can I cause auto-correct in Lion to beep and to get a summary of the changes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19597/can-i-cause-auto-correct-in-lion-to-beep-and-to-get-a-summary-of-the-changes?lq=1)

but (a) they are more concerned with auto-correct; (b) they are a few years old; and (c) they don’t have a real solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42549/is-it-possible-to-hack-the-correct-spelling-automatically-setting-in-os-x-to-e?rq=1 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19597/can-i-cause-auto-correct-in-lion-to-beep-and-to-get-a-summary-of-the-changes?lq=1

Comment: @GrahamMiln No, it isn’t. The linked question (a) is 3 years old, and therefore possibly out of date; (b) is not fully answered; (c) refers to auto correction which _mine specifically excludes_.

Comment: If the old question needs an answer, we edit it or promote it with bounties. If you can explain how OS X treats spelling correction differently than auto-correct, please edit that into the post. Everything I've seen is that the same exact code handles both so a beep from one will be a beep from the other. Also, don't say "this is different" just edit it so it's clear it's different...